# How to concatenate multiple columns with a coma between them

Tags: r, concatenation

I have the following data frame in r

```
ID COL.1  COL.2  COL.3  COL.4

1  a      b  
2  v      b      b 
3  x      a      n      h 
4  t
```

I am new to R and I don't understand how to call the data fram in order to have this   at the end, another problem is that i have more than 100 columns

```
stream   <- c("1,a,b","2,v,b,b","3,x,a,n,h","4,t")
```

another problem is that I have more than 100 columns .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Reduce(function(...)paste(...,sep=","), df)
```

Where df is your data.frame

Comment: Or similarly - `do.call(paste, c(dat, sep=",") )`

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for, even though it's not elegant.

```
my_df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1, 4, by = 1), 
                COL.1 = c("a", "v", "x", "t"), 
                COL.2 = c("b", "b", "a", NULL),
                COL.3 = c(NULL, "b", "n", NULL),
                COL.4 = c(NULL, NULL, "h", NULL))
stream <- substring(paste(my_df$ID, 
                      my_df$COL.1, 
                      my_df$COL.2, 
                      my_df$COL.3, 
                      my_df$COL.4,
                      sep =","), 3)
stream <- gsub(",NA", "", stream)
stream <- gsub("NA,", "", stream)
```